# Name for matrix associated to smooth continuation

Tags: matrices, terminology, notation

Is there an established name for the matrices that establish the conditions for a linear combination of $n$ functions $\lbrace f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x)\rbrace$ being the $n$-times smoothly differentiable continuation of a function $g(x)$ for $x=x_0$ after adding an appropriate constant:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{d}{dx}f_1(x_0)&\dots&\frac{d}{dx}f_n(x_0)\\ \vdots & &\vdots\\ \frac{d^n}{dx^n}f_1(x_0) & \dots & \frac{d^n}{dx^n}f_n(x_0)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}c_1 \\ \vdots\\ c_n\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}g'(x_0)\\ \vdots\\ g^{(n)}(x_0)\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: According to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#Definition), it would be the derivative of what is sometimes called a "fundamental matrix".

Comment: @pregunton thank you very much, that ianswers my question

Comment: @pregunton Could you formulate it as an answer? Answering in comment is not a good practice on Stack Exchange sites. (In addition, you'll get internet points for it your answer.)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni My apologies. I expanded the comment into an answer.

Comment: No worries, and thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#Definition), the matrix in the question is the derivative of what is sometimes called a *fundamental matrix*. A Google search of that term together with "Wronskian" gives quite a few relevant hits, so the name seems to be in common use.